# How do I wait for each of these promises to execute asynchronously?

Tags: feathersjs

conversation.user and conversation.secondUser are appended to the conversation object but the nested messages loop executes after the response is sent to the client.

```
    find: [
        async (context) => {
            await Promise.all(context.result.data.map((conversation) => {
                return context.app.service('users').get(conversation.userId).then((data) => {
                    conversation.user = data;

                    return context.app.service('users').get(conversation.secondUserId).then((data) => {
                        conversation.secondUser = data;

                        return conversation.messages.map((message) => {
                            return context.app.service('users').get(message.userId).then((data) => {
                                console.log(data);
                                message.user = data;
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            }));

            context.dispatch = context.result;
            return context;
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You forgot a `Promise.all` in the last section
2. You are making your life harder by not fully making use of `async/await`

This should work:

```
find: [
  async (context) => {
    await Promise.all(context.result.data.map(async (conversation) => {
      const data = await context.app.service('users').get(conversation.userId);
      const secondData = await context.app.service('users').get(conversation.secondUserId);

      conversation.user = data;
      conversation.secondUser = secondData;

      await Promise.all(conversation.messages.map(async (message) => {
        const data = await context.app.service('users').get(message.userId);

        console.log(data);
        message.user = data;
      }));
    }));

    context.dispatch = context.result;

    return context;
  }
]
```